# Populate Dropdown list on webpage from an iFrame with VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I've got a code which opens a webpage and clicks on a link. This then loads data from an Iframe, which I'm trying to change values on dropdown lists.

I'm trying to populate the `Manufr`dropdown list from the `Year` iFrame. using VBA, but I'm getting a `Object Variable or With Block Variable not set` error. Could this have something to do with the fact that the data I am trying to edit is in an Iframe?

Here is the code I'm trying to use

```
Sub Scrape2()
    Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim element As IHTMLElement

    Set Browser = New InternetExplorer
    Browser.Visible = True
    Browser.navigate "http://catalog.xxxxxxx.com"

    Do While Browser.Busy And Not Browser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop

        For Each l In Browser.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
        If l = "http://catalog.xxxxx.com/Catalog.asp?VehicleRef=2" Then
            l.Click
            Exit For
        End If
        Next



    Stop

    Set Doc = Browser.document

        Dim mainIframe
        Dim subIframe
        Set mainIframe = Doc.frames.Item(1).document
        Set subIframe = mainIframe.frames.Item(0).document
        Set element = mainIframe.getElementById("Manufacturer").selectedIndex = 1
        element.FireEvent ("onchange")

    Set Doc = Nothing
    Set Browser = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the first link click do?  Do you need to wait for that event to complete?

Comment: First link loads an iframe in the document. Could it be that the data is embedded in an Iframe, that is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes the document in the frame is not the same document as the one you're working with.  And you'll need to allow it time to load.

Comment: OK so how can I reference data in the Iframe? I can figure out the code to wait for it to load.    The Frame name is "Year"   and the dropdown field that I want to modify in that Iframe is "Manufacturer"

Comment: Does the frame have an id, or just a name?

Comment: `Document.frames("Manufacturer").document`

Comment: `<iframe name="Year" width="330" height="100" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="LoadManufacturers.asp?VehicleRef=2&amp;Manufacturer="> </iframe>`

Comment: Sorry - got the fame name mixed up. Should have been Year.

Comment: OK thanks. So then how would I go about selecting and changing the "Manufacturer" dropdown field in this iframe? Do I need to use another object? Can you show me the code, maybe put it in an answer below? I appreciate the help Tim!

Comment: Awesome post, I'm having exactly the same problem! @ColinMason please post your working solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim d2
Set d2 = Doc.frames("Year").document

Set element = d2.getElementById("Manufacturer").selectedIndex = 1
element.FireEvent ("onchange")
```

EDIT: try this

```
Dim d2, evt
Set d2 = Doc.frames("main").document.frames("year").document
Set element = d2.getElementById("Manufacturer")

If Not element Is nothing Then

    Debug.Print "Got drop-down"
    element.selectedIndex = 1

    'either this...
    element.FireEvent ("onchange")

    'or try this...
    Set evt = d2.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    evt.initEvent "change", True, False
    element.dispatchEvent evt

Else
    Debug.Print "couldn't get drop-down!"
End if
```

Comment: You need to add a wait after clicking the first link (or for testing purposes you could put a break on `Set Doc = Browser.Document` and wait until the page is loaded before continuing)

Comment: Difficult to offer much else without some way to test.  Can you provide a URL?

Comment: Hi Tim, I managed to get it to work using main index of (0) and sub index of (0)

Comment: Tim, any way I can write a code to wait for the iFrame to load? I've tried the `Do While Browser.Busy` code but that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Haven't done that myself - if you google around you may find some examples.